# Typescript private class inside class or something similar

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'd like to declare a private class, only to be used inside the file it was defined, is this possible?
For example declared inside another class:

```
export class MyParentClass {
    class MyChildClass {
    }
}
```

or inside the same file:

```
export class MyPublicClass {
   //Usage of MyPrivateClass 
}

class MyPrivateClass {
}
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

```
module MyModule {
    export class MyPublicClass {
        private myPrivateClass: PrivateClass;
        constructor() {
            this.myPrivateClass = new PrivateClass;
        }
        public test() {
            this.myPrivateClass.test();
        }
    }

    class PrivateClass {
        public test() {
            console.log('it works');
        }
    }
}
```